# How to override edit_orm_one_to_one.html.twig in SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

How can i ovverride template SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle / Resources / views / CRUD /edit_orm_one_to_one.html.twig in SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you would override any other vendor bundle. Take a look over [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html) in the Symfony documentation. Make sure you copy over the whole directory structure of the vendor bundle and then only place the files in it that you need to override.